# Scream: Error suppression ignored for Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty:PHP5

Tags: php, smarty

I get this error

> Scream: Error suppression ignored for Fatal error: Uncaught -->
>   Smarty:PHP5 requires you to call_construct() instead of smarty() <--
>   thrown in
>   C:\tshirtshop\lib\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   line 855

anytime I try to load up `"http://localhost/tshrtshop"`.

Comment: Pretty sure your error is telling you the problem ;)

Comment: It's hard to say anything without your code. But maybe you use very old Smarty version or probably you did something wrong. Without code it's hard to say.

Comment: yeah, obviously. i know the error is telling me the problem, but figuring it out is the issue am having here. would have fixed or should i say solve it if it could decipher it. @ Marcin, what other codes do you need i supply? The question seem straight forward isn't it?

Comment: @Ribo01 What Smarty version do you use? What PHP version do you use? What is `Scream`? Have you downloaded Smarty from official site and tried to run demo ? If everything is ok, if you run ` <?php require 'smarty/Smarty.class.php'; $smarty = new Smarty();` should not generate any errors and warnings if you put Smarty into smarty directory.

Comment: thanks Marcin for the write back. My PHP version is 5, 5.43 to be precise. the smarty i downloaded is ver 3.1.19.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you extend Smarty somehow with your custom class.

If you simple create object  you should do it this way:

```
$view = new Smarty();
```

and in case you extend you should call:

```
parent::__construct();
```

and not

```
parent::Smarty();
```